# How to let Excel push a button automatically based on a cell value

Tags: excel

I have a sheet for deadlines reminders.
I added a button to send an email and it's working fine
I need to add a code to let Excel push the button automatically if a cell value is less than 5

I need the Excel to push the button automatically once a cell value is less than 5.
this cell value reflects the number of days remaining for the deadline

Comment: You might consider either the `Worksheet.Change` event or the `Worksheet.Calculate` event, depending on whether that cell contains a hard-coded value or a formula.

Comment: i'm using the below code

**Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Range("D1").Value < 5 Then
Call Button1_Click
End If
End Sub**


but i receive a compile error 'sub or function not defined'

Comment: Is the 'button' a *Forms* or an *Active-X* control'? In which module is `Button1_Click` located? Consider using an extra cell that would contain a flag to be checked so the email doesn't get sent repeatedly on each calculation.